# Mulesoft Kafka connector and Amazon MSK

Tags: apache-kafka, mulesoft, mule4, aws-msk, amazon-msk

I am trying to connect Mulesoft to Amazon MSK using the Kafka connector. I followed the steps from amazon https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/getting-started.html but not sure if I need to create that EC2 instance.. is a requirement or just for the demo they give? Have anyone had tried this connection before?

Thanks.

Mulesoft IDEAS portal: https://help.mulesoft.com/s/ideas#0872T0000009uqgQAA

Comment: Where does Mulesoft run? The "client" machine that you would make is to just run your code or `kafka-console-*` tools.

Comment: The Mule runtime will be running locally on my machine and eventually on Cloudhub.. The POC project will be simple: Scheduler -> Set payload --> Kafka producer --> Logger

Comment: If you play to install it in AWS, then yes, you need an EC2